# Cypress interaction with elements outside the DOM

Tags: user-interface

I am kind of new here, although I read often the posts, that is why, first of all, a big thank you for all the help we get here. If there is someone using Cypress, I have a problem with accessing a print dialog which is outside the DOM. I want to close the print dialog but I cannot access it using the Cypress commands. I had the same problem with Python and Selenium, but there I managed to install AutoGui and this helped me out.
Anyone had the same problem and found a solution to it? Thank you in advance.

```
**                                                                                                      **
```